# $\lim_{h\to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f_h(x)-f(x)|^p \, dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Supppose $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \in L^p(\mathbb R)$. Let $f_h(x) = \frac{1}{2h}\int^{x+h}_{x-h}f(t)\,dt$, show that:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \int_{\mathbb R} |f_h(x)-f(x)|^p \, dx = 0$$

By Lesbegue integration theorem we know that $\lim_{h\to 0} f_h(x) = f(x)$, and inspired by this, the natural next step is to use Dominated Convergence Theorem. Is this doable? I cannot really come up with a bound for $f_h(x)$.

Comment: DCT can be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct DCT proof. So instead, the following:

First assume that $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, that is, $f$ is compactly supported and smooth. Then the DCT argument works. (I guess we just needed, e.g., compact support and an $L^\infty$ bound for this)

Since $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p$, for any given $f \in L^p$, take $(g_n)_n \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ with $g_n \to f$ in $L^p$. Take $\epsilon > 0$. Take $n$ large so that $||f-g_n||_p < \epsilon/3$. Take $h_\epsilon > 0$ so that $$|h| \le h_\epsilon \implies \int_\mathbb{R} |(g_n)_h(x)-g_n(x)|^p dx < \epsilon/3.$$ Since $||(g_n)_h - f_h||_p^p = ||g_n-f||_p^p$ (check this), we see that for $|h| \le h_\epsilon$, $$||f-f_h||_p \le ||f-g_n||_p + ||g_n-(g_n)_h||_p + ||(g_n)_h - f_h||_p \le \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 = \epsilon.$$

Comment: Nice proof. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually your $ f_h $ is dominated by Hardy Littlewood Maximal function $ Mf (x) $ meaning $ f_h(x)\le Mf (x) $, and also using the known  estimate $||Mf (x)||_{L^p} \le C||f(x)||_{L^p}$, where  $ C $ is a constant independent of $ f $. So DCT can be applied.

Comment: this doesn't work for $p=1$